# Xbox 360 wireless receiver taking up all my joystick slots

Tags: usb, games, gamepad

I have two controllers, a XBox 360 with wireless receiver and a retro snes iBuffalo, each one connected to a USB port.

Both works fine, but the xbox receiver creates 4 instances of controllers, probably because it supports up to that number of connections. The thing is that when I launch a game such as Crawl or Towerfall this instances takes up the controller slots and my snes USB controller is not detected.

Is there a way to disable the additional instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the problem itself, the Xbox360 wireless receiver supports four controllers and the kernel driver makes them all available even if no controller is connected. This could be considered a bug in the driver, but also has advantages such as allowing you to hotplug controller when a game is already running.

Anyway, as for fixing the situation, the quick and dirty way to fix the problem temporarily:

```
rm /dev/input/js1
rm /dev/input/js2
rm /dev/input/js3
mv /dev/input/js4 /dev/input/js1
```

This will just rename the input devices and move the unused Xbox360 devices out of the way. This won't survive a reboot, as the device names get reassigned automatically each time.

For a more permanent fix you have to write some udev rules to change the way how devices are named when they are plugged in:

- http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html